# Cannot read this xml with python?

Tags: python, xhtml

I know next to nothing about xhtml. And I've got to write a python script to edit a table. But the wiki page I have to edit is for some reason not being read by any of the python xml parsers, and I haven't a clue what's going on. This is a sample page of the wiki. Can anyone tell me what the heck is wrong with this?

```
<h2>test</h2><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>I am a test</strong></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Now I need a table</p><table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>column</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td><p>data2</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Here's a bit of the code I've been trying to read this with. I've gone through several iterations and different xml parsers, the pulldom, xml.dom, ElementTree, minidom, etc. They're all giving the same exception:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
def main( argv ):
    fileName = "/home/robbnic/Source/scripts/Gesture Service Dashboard.txt"
    text = readFromFile(fileName)
    try:
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(fileName):
            if elem.tag == "table":
                print "Hot damn!"
                elem.clear()
    except ET.ParseError as pe:
         print pe.message
         print pe.msg
         print pe.args
         print pe.filename
    except:
         print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
         raise
```

The exception error I keep getting is unbound prefix, but I know so little about xml (or xhtml in this case) that I just don't know what's going on.

Comment: That looks like html, not xml.

Comment: Can you include some of the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: Ah, it's supposed to be xhtml from a confluence site. Lemme edit my post!

Comment: What do you mean by "edit a table"? Are you looking to change the original XHTML code within the document (inserting or replacing code), or are you looking to access the value of a particular node and manipulate the stored value in memory? (like for web scraping)

Comment: I mean I'll need to edit the contents of the cells, or add new rows or columns based on an input text file full of data.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a single root tag. You cannot have multiple roots as yours does (i.e. the `h2`, `p`s, `table`, etc.).

Comment: What, you mean I just kind of stick something on there that says <root> ?

Comment: Sure. The exact tag name isn't *terribly* important, so long as it's valid XML. And don't forget to close it after.